# Using WhatsApp on Web, but camera not working?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, camera

I'd like to use WhatsApp on my web browser but I can't scan the QR code. Opening the scanner on the QR code brings the error "*Cannot start camera*" Is there any workaround to scanning the WhatsApp web QR code without using WhatsApp's inbuilt camera scanner?

Comment: Does the camera only says this, or the Whatsapp itself has the issue of unable to use Camera somehow? May be you could post a screenshot of the error in Whatsapp. Also, have you restarted the phone? // Did you do something (root, app install, or similar) prior to the starting of the issue?